# Connecting to a server with a name rather than a ip address

Tags: networking, ip, wamp

I have a wamp server running on my computer.

I can connect to the server with my iPad on Safari by running the ip address, 192.168.1.108 (this is the ip of the wireless network connection).

Both the tablet and the computer are connected to a Cisco router.

I wanted to know how to connect the tablet to the server with a name rather that the ip address 192.168.1.108. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a name resolver; options are:

- [Hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) on your OSs (all devices)
- [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)
- Other resolvers (e.g. WINS)

The most viable way for such a small environment is configuring Hosts file.